# Doing an UpdateAsync in MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the below class structure. I'm trying to call UpdateAsync by passing only a part of the object. For some reason it is respecting the BsonIgnoreIfDefault only at the root object level TestObject class, but not on TestProduct.

```
public class TestObject
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string KoId { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public TestProduct Product { get; set; }
}

public class TestProduct
{
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public List<string> Skus { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a snippet of my integration test:

```
public async Task EndToEndHappyPath()
{
    const string summary = "This is a summary";
    var obj = new TestObject
    {
        Summary = summary,
        KoaId = "1234",
        Product = new TestProduct
        {
            Name = "laptop",
            Skus = new List<string>
            {
                "Memory"
            }
        }
    };

    // CREATE
    await _mongoAsyncRepository.CreateAsync(obj);

    obj = new TestObject
    {
        KoaId = koaId,
        Description = description,
        Product = new TestProduct
        {
            Skus = new List<string>
            {
                "RAM"
            }
        }
    };

    // UPDATE
    var response = await _mongoAsyncRepository.UpdateAsync(koaId, obj);
    response.ShouldBeTrue();

    // RETRIEVE
    result = await _mongoAsyncRepository.RetrieveOneAsync(koaId);
    testObject = (result as TestObject);
    testObject.Product.ShouldNotBeNull();
    // this is failing; Name value is null in MongoDb
    testObject.Product.Name.ShouldBe("laptop");
    testObject.Product.Skus.ShouldNotBeNull();
    testObject.Product.Skus.Count.ShouldBe(1);
    testObject.Product.Skus[0].ShouldBe("RAM");
}

public async Task<bool> UpdateAsync(string id, T obj)
{
    try
    {
        _logger.Log(new KoaLogEntry(KoaLogLevel.Debug, $"Attempting to update a {typeof(T)} {id} document."));

        //var actionResult = await GetMongoCollection()?.ReplaceOneAsync(new BsonDocument("KoaId", id), obj);

        var updated = new BsonDocument
{
    {
        "$set", bsonDoc
    }
};
UpdateDefinition<BsonDocument> updatedObj = UpdateBuilder.DefinitionFor(updated);


        var actionResult = await GetMongoCollection()?.UpdateOneAsync(new BsonDocument("KoaId", id), updated);

        _logger.Log(new KoaLogEntry(KoaLogLevel.Debug, $"Updated a {typeof(T)} {id} document. IsAcknowledged = {actionResult.IsAcknowledged}; ModifiedCount = {actionResult.ModifiedCount}"));

        return actionResult.IsAcknowledged
               && actionResult.ModifiedCount > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        _logger.Log(new KoaLogEntry(KoaLogLevel.Error, exc.Message, exc));
        throw;
    }
}

private readonly IMongoClient _client;

protected IMongoCollection<T> GetMongoCollection()
{
    var database = _client.GetDatabase(this.DatabaseName);
    return database.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);
}
```

For some reason Name is getting overwritten to null though I have put the BsonIgnoreIfDefault attribute on it.

Please let me know what I'm missing.
Thanks
Arun

Comment: It looks like you're using a repository lib? Which lib and what's the type of _mongoAsyncRepository?

Comment: Good point @ChristophLütjen. Internally it calls the MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient library.

Comment: I find it strange that no one has encountered this problem. Please assist.

Comment: it's the code in your repository that's not working as you expect it to work. Could you please provide this code?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen.. updated the main question with the method details.

Comment: Hope this question is not that difficult to answer and implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and it seems that this is not supported out of the box.

BsonIgnoreIfDefault means "do not include in document in db if default" it does NOT mean "ignore in updates".

Your update command

```
var actionResult = await GetMongoCollection()?.UpdateOneAsync(new BsonDocument("KoaId", id), updated);
```

should have the same behavior as this:

```
await GetMongoCollection().ReplaceOneAsync(_ => _.KoaId == id, obj);
```

It will replace the the existing document.

The docs say (and I assume, that the c# driver does no magic):

> If the  document contains only field:value expressions, then:
>   The update() method replaces the matching document with the  document. The update() method does not replace the _id value. For an example, see Replace All Fields.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

So you're doing a replace and all properties having default values will not be written to new new document:

```
// document after replace without annotations (pseudocode, fragment only)
{ 
  KoaId: "abc",
  Summary: null
}

// with Summary annotated with BsonIgnoreIfDefault
{ 
  KoaId: "abc"
}
```

The only solution I found, is to write a builder that creates UpdateDefinitions from an object and add custom attributes. This is my first version that may help as a start:

```
/// <summary>
///     Ignore property in updates build with UpdateBuilder.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class BsonUpdateIgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}

/// <summary>
///     Ignore this property in UpdateBuild if it's value is null
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class BsonUpdateIgnoreIfNullAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public static class UpdateBuilder
{
    public static UpdateDefinition<TDocument> DefinitionFor<TDocument>(TDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(document));

        var updates = _getUpdateDefinitions<TDocument>("", document);
        return Builders<TDocument>.Update.Combine(updates);
    }

    private static IList<UpdateDefinition<TDocument>> _getUpdateDefinitions<TDocument>(string prefix, object root)
    {
        var properties = root.GetType().GetProperties();
        return properties
            .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<BsonUpdateIgnoreAttribute>() == null)
            .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<BsonUpdateIgnoreIfNullAttribute>() == null || p.GetValue(root) != null)
            .Select(p => _getUpdateDefinition<TDocument>(p, prefix, root)).ToList();
    }

    private static UpdateDefinition<TDocument> _getUpdateDefinition<TDocument>(PropertyInfo propertyInfo,
        string prefix,
        object obj)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsClass &&
            !propertyInfo.PropertyType.Namespace.AsSpan().StartsWith("System") &&
            propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) != null)
        {
            prefix = prefix + propertyInfo.Name + ".";
            return Builders<TDocument>.Update.Combine(
                _getUpdateDefinitions<TDocument>(prefix, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj)));
        }

        return Builders<TDocument>.Update.Set(prefix + propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(obj));
    }
}
```

Please not that this is not optimized for performance.

You can use it like so:

```
        var updateDef = UpdateBuilder.DefinitionFor(updatedDocument);
        await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(_ => _.Id == id, updateDef);
```

Comment: Getting serialization issue: Parameter count mismatch. I've updated my code in the original post to reflect your suggestion as well. On second thoughts, if this is this complex, isn't it easier to just read the entire document from the repo, update parts of it and save it again? Obviously not efficient, but would work right? Something for MongoDB team to work on I guess!

Comment: Reading the record first is a common option. (while you still have the work to compare old and new document). Another option is to think in "commands" that are made for a special partial update. E.g. we have a "user" document and an update method "UpdatePassword" that accepts the new password and will do exactly this (using a single set operation). If you can split you use cases I'd recommend to go that route.

Comment: Sir, your suggestion of using specific commands is in the works for version 2.. where we've split the document into smaller chunks. Due to lack of time, we'll read the document, update parts of it and save it. I want to know what to do with ticket. I don't want to mark it as answer since it didn't work for me, but I'd like to give you credit for your time and assistance. Please advise.

Comment: Your question was "why is BsonIgnoreIfDefault attribute not working". My answer is "because you misunderstood the meaning of this attribute. So I'd say it's the correct answer. But if you don't want to accept it, that's totally ok for me.

Comment: Sir, makes sense. Marked your post as the answer.